# toggle on double click, jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I show or hide a div on double click with jquery?

```
$("body").dblclick(function() { 
            $("#plot_on_map_form").show("medium").css({top: event.pageY,left: event.pageX});
        },
        function() {
            $("#plot_on_map_form").css({display:"none"});
    }
);
```

Comment: I am making a small form visible on top of a Google map.  I am capturing the x and y coords of where the user clicks so that the form appears next to where they clicked on the map.  On dblclick, I need to make visible and set top and left CSS elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>Div</div>

$(document).dblclick(function(){
    $('div').toggle();
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dth9R/

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery docs   http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle
you can try like this for show and hide

```
 $("li").dblclick(function() {
       if($(this).didSomeThing == true){
           $(this).backToNormal();
           $(this).didSomeThing = false;
           return;
       }
       $(this).doSomething();
       $(this).didSomeThing = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used two function blocks, but in this case this will not work here.

use one function block and use jquery function toggle().

this will solve the problem.